# google sheets api v4 clear command POST format

Tags: javascript, rest, post, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

So, I am making a simple little program for work that retrieves a current sheet from google sheets using the following javascript

```
const key = ("KEY");
const SHEETID =("SHEET");
setInterval(function(){
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            addRow("orders",xmlHttp.responseText);
    },5000);
}

xmlHttp.open("GET","https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/SHEETID/values/Sheet1/?key="+key, true); // true for asynchronous 
xmlHttp.send(null)
function addRow(tbl_nme,responseText){
    console.log(responseText)
    var obj = JSON.parse(responseText);
    setInterval(function(){
        getrowI(tbl_nme,obj)
    },5000);
}
```

This part works fine and I can render this into a html5 table with a button on it.
However when I go to post a command to remove a row from a google spreadsheet using the clear API, I get a 401 error and I can't figure out what I am doing 
wrong.

the POST code i use looks like this:

```
function postoff(cel){
    console.log(cel);
    var posturl = ("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/SHEETID/values/"+"!A"+cel+":"+"F"+cel+":clear"+"?key="+key);
    axios.post(posturl);
}
```

according to  https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/clear

My format should be close, but not sure what I am doing wrong. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: I think that the reason of your issue is that API key is used for POST method. Although API key can be used for GET method, it cannot be used for POST and PUT method. So how about using the access token from OAuth2 or service account?

Comment: I will try that and report back.

Comment: Yeah, Using OAuth2 is not easy to do with axios. I am going to have to rewrite this using google's actual API. Thank you for the help.